# Wordle color algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, wordle

A lot of Wordle clones get the tile-coloring algorithm wrong: for example,

- if the word is BURNT and you guess TOAST, the colors should be ----G (not Y---G)
- if the word is MAXIM and you guess MAMMA, the colors should be GGY-- (not GGYYY)
- if the word is SWIFT and you guess IIWIS, the colors should be Y-Y-Y (not YYYYY)

I've written a JavaScript implementation of the tile-coloring algorithm. I'd like to know both whether it's *correct* (non-buggy), and how it can be *improved*. In particular, if there's some way to compute *just* the color of the `index`th tile, without computing all the tiles' colors as a side effect, that would be nice to know.

````
function computeColor(targetWord, guess, index) {
  let colors = Array(WORD_LENGTH).fill("wrong")
  for (var i = 0; i < WORD_LENGTH; ++i) {
    if (targetWord[i] === guess[i]) {
      colors[i] = "correct"
    } else if (targetWord.includes(guess[i])) {
      colors[i] = "wrong-location"
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < WORD_LENGTH; ++i) {
    if (colors[i] == "wrong-location") {
      // Only the correct number of tiles should be colored yellow.
      const letter = guess[i]
      const targetCount = targetWord.split('').filter((ch) => ch == letter).length
      const greenCount = Array.from(Array(WORD_LENGTH).keys()).filter((j) => (guess[j] === letter && colors[j] === "correct")).length
      const maxYellowCount = targetCount - greenCount
      let currentYellowCount = 0
      for (var j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (guess[j] == letter && colors[j] === "wrong-location") {
          currentYellowCount += 1
        }
      }
      if (currentYellowCount == maxYellowCount) {
        colors[i] = "wrong"
      }
    }
  }
  return colors[index]
}

console.assert(computeColor('BURNT', 'TOAST', 0) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('BURNT', 'TOAST', 1) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('BURNT', 'TOAST', 2) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('BURNT', 'TOAST', 3) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('BURNT', 'TOAST', 4) === "correct")

console.assert(computeColor('MAXIM', 'MAMMA', 0) === "correct")
console.assert(computeColor('MAXIM', 'MAMMA', 1) === "correct")
console.assert(computeColor('MAXIM', 'MAMMA', 2) === "wrong-location")
console.assert(computeColor('MAXIM', 'MAMMA', 3) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('MAXIM', 'MAMMA', 4) === "wrong")

console.assert(computeColor('SWIFT', 'IIWIS', 0) === "wrong-location")
console.assert(computeColor('SWIFT', 'IIWIS', 1) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('SWIFT', 'IIWIS', 2) === "wrong-location")
console.assert(computeColor('SWIFT', 'IIWIS', 3) === "wrong")
console.assert(computeColor('SWIFT', 'IIWIS', 4) === "wrong-location")
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REVISED**

---

Code should be correct, maintainable, robust, reasonably efficient, and, most important, readable.

---

Wordle is a clever, challenging, and fun game implemented by a skilled software engineer.

> Hi, I'm Josh [Wardle].
> https://powerlanguage.co.uk/
>
> [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) is daily word guessing game I made.

The Wordle tile coloring rules are:

> Guess the WORDLE in six tries.
>
> Each guess must be a valid five-letter word. Hit the enter button to submit.
>
> After each guess, the color of the tiles will change to show how close your guess was to the word.
>
> Green:   The letter is in the word and in the correct spot.
>
> Yellow:  The letter is in the word but in the wrong spot.
>
> Gray:    The letter is not in the word in any spot.

---

Review 1 is a code review that critiques the OP's code and provides a revised, simplified version of the OP's code that conforms to Wordle rules. The revised code efficiently satisfies the rule that five letters must be entered before the color of the tiles change by returning a five letter array of tile colors.

---

In a comment on Review 1, the OP says: "the "wordle.js" I'm plugging this into expects a function with the given signature [`(word, guess, index)`]; I wanted to surgically replace just the buggy coloring function."

Review 2 refactors the revised solution from Review 1 to provide an efficient function with the expected signature: `(word, guess, index)`.

---

---

**REVIEW 1**

> I'd like to know whether it's correct

Your code is complicated. It's hard to prove it is correct.

---

Production executable code, like Wordle, is minified, use spacing and useful comments to enhance readability.

The letter background colors will be used both inside and outside the function. Use outside the function color constants.

Simplify your code. In particular, eliminate extraneous methods: `split`, `filter`, `from`, `keys`, and so on. Some of these methods implement implicit loops, which, inside a `for` loop, have O(n**2) complexity. The simplified code has only two loops with O(n) complexity.

Don't use `var` for variable declarations. Use `let` or `const`.

Don't use `==` for equality; use `===` for strict equality.

There is no reason to limit the function to five letter words and guesses. However, check the function word and guess length equality invariant.

The simplfied code, as required by Wordle, returns a complete array of letter background colors. The original function only returns the color for a single letter. There is (times five) computational rundundancy to color all five letters of a guess.

Using jsbench.me, coloring a five letter guess using the original code is over 90% slower than the simplified code.

---

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
// letter background colors
const COLOR_NOT_ENTERED   = "White";
const COLOR_CORRECT_SPOT  = "Green";
const COLOR_WRONG_SPOT    = "Yellow";
const COLOR_NOT_ANY_SPOT  = "Gray";

// guessColors returns an array of guess letter background colors.
function guessColors(word, guess) { 
    let colors = new Array(guess.length);
    if (word.length !== guess.length) {
        return colors.fill(COLOR_NOT_ENTERED);
    }

    // color matched guess letters as correct-spot, 
    // and count unmatched word letters
    let unmatched = {}; // unmatched word letters
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        let letter = word[i];
        if (letter === guess[i]) {
            colors[i] = COLOR_CORRECT_SPOT;
        } else {
            unmatched[letter] = (unmatched[letter] || 0) + 1;
        }
    }

    // color unmatched guess letters right-to-left, 
    // allocating remaining word letters as wrong-spot,
    // otherwise, as not-any-spot
    for (let i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
        let letter = guess[i];
        if (letter !== word[i]) {
            if (unmatched[letter]) {
                colors[i] = COLOR_WRONG_SPOT;
                unmatched[letter]--;
            } else {
                colors[i] = COLOR_NOT_ANY_SPOT;
            }
        }
    }

    return colors;
}
```

---

---

> if there's some way to compute just the color of the indexth tile, without computing all the tiles' colors as a side effect.

There is not. Why do you want to do that?

---

Consider a word

```
[ A X A A A ]
```

and a partial (index 0) guess of

```
[ X - - - - ]
```

which evaluates to colors

```
[ Yellow, ------, ------, ------, ------ ]
```

Now, add another letter to the guess, a partial (index 1) guess of

```
[ X X - - - ]
```

which evaluates to colors

```
[ Grey,   Green,  ------, ------, ------ ]
```

Partial colors evaluation is not always stable.

---

---

**REVIEW 2**

---

Here is a revised, simplified version of the OP's code to provide a more readable, more efficient function with the expected signature: `(word, guess, index)`.

Using [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/), the OP's code is about 96% slower than the following simplified code. The simplified code is about 25 times faster. The simplified code only has one loop. The simplified code does not contain extraneous code.

> [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) rules:
>
> Each guess must be a valid five-letter word.
> Hit the enter button to submit.
> After each guess, the color of the tiles will change.

For an official, accurate Wordle guess tile color, on each call to the function "guess must be a five-letter word." Wait until the guess is submitted: "Hit the enter button to submit."

A simple example illustrates the problem. Using Wordle rules, tile color depends on guess letters before and after guess[index]:

```
AXAAA
X
[ 'Yellow', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray' ]
AXAAA
XX
[ 'Gray', 'Green', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray' ]
```

The tile color for guess[0] varies depending on how many guess letters are entered.

Also, coloring tiles before the guess is complete would ruin the game by making it too easy.

---

```
// Wordle letter tile background colors
const COLOR_CORRECT_SPOT  = "Green";
const COLOR_WRONG_SPOT    = "Yellow";
const COLOR_NOT_ANY_SPOT  = "Gray";

// guessColor returns the guess[index] letter tile background color.
// 
// Wordle tile coloring rules: 
// Each guess must be a valid five-letter word. 
// Hit the enter button to submit. 
// After each guess, the color of the tiles will change.
// Green:   The letter is in the word and in the correct spot.   
// Yellow:  The letter is in the word but in the wrong spot.   
// Gray:    The letter is not in the word in any spot.   
function guessColor(word, guess, index) {
    // correct (matched) index letter
    if (guess[index] === word[index]) {
        return COLOR_CORRECT_SPOT;
    }

    let wrongWord = wrongGuess = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        // count the wrong (unmatched) letters
        if (word[i] === guess[index] && guess[i] !== guess[index] ) {
            wrongWord++;
        }
        if (i <= index) {
            if (guess[i] === guess[index] && word[i] !== guess[index]) {
                wrongGuess++;
            }
        }

        // an unmatched guess letter is wrong if it pairs with 
        // an unmatched word letter
        if (i >= index) {
            if (wrongGuess === 0) {
                break;
            } 
            if (wrongGuess <= wrongWord) {
                return COLOR_WRONG_SPOT;
            }
        }
    }

    // otherwise not any
    return COLOR_NOT_ANY_SPOT;
}
```

---

```
function testGuessColor(tests) {
    for (let [word, guess] of tests) {
        console.log(word);
        console.log(guess);
        let colors = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            colors.push(guessColor(word, guess, i));
        }
        console.log(colors);
    }
}

let tests = [
    ['BURNT', 'TOAST'],
    ['MAXIM', 'MAMMA'],
    ['SWIFT', 'IIWIS'],
    ['ABBEY', 'BOBBY'],
    ["ABCDE", "ABCDE"],
    ["ABCDE", "VWXYZ"],
];
testGuessColor(tests);
```

---

```
$ node wordle.js
BURNT
TOAST
[ 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Green' ]
MAXIM
MAMMA
[ 'Green', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Gray', 'Gray' ]
SWIFT
IIWIS
[ 'Yellow', 'Gray', 'Yellow', 'Gray', 'Yellow' ]
ABBEY
BOBBY
[ 'Yellow', 'Gray', 'Green', 'Gray', 'Green' ]
ABCDE
ABCDE
[ 'Green', 'Green', 'Green', 'Green', 'Green' ]
ABCDE
VWXYZ
[ 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray', 'Gray' ]
$
```

Comment: I could disagree with a lot of your comments, but ultimately your implementation was the most helpful in rewriting mine. The idea of looping first over the targetWord, then over the guess, is clever. Re "Why do you want to do that?": Because the "wordle.js" I'm plugging this into expects a function with the given signature; I wanted to surgically replace *just* the buggy coloring function. Your example shows why we need to look at all 5 letters in order to compute the color of tile 0, but it doesn't prove that we need to compute all 5 tiles' final _colors_ just in order to compute tile 0's.

Comment: Re `keys`, `filter`, etc: The "wordle.js" I'm plugging this into gets away (somehow) with no other for-loops; I was introducing the only for-loops (and thus the only semicolons) in the entire script. So I was feeling a bit guilty about that, and looking for ways to express "count the Xs in Y" without for-loops. My efforts didn't even pay off: I ended up with three(!) for-loops anyway! But anyway, that's the story of why I didn't just write for-loops to do the counting at first. I think `for (let i in guess)` would work for both of these loops, but I assume that'd be considered obfuscatory...

Comment: @Quuxplusone: See my revised answer, especially, the Review 2 section.

Answer (score 2):

My very first thought was, let's change the function signature to `computeColors(targetWord, guess)` and have it return all the colors as a 5-character string in your specified format: `G` for green, `Y` for yellow, and `-` for gray. `computeColor` currently throws away a lot of good work, only to return the appraisal of a single letter in `guess`, when we could be returning the colors for the entire guess.

Your algorithm is correct as far as I can tell; I tried a few more test cases from my previous Wordle reviews and they all passed. That being said, the nested iterating & tracking for `currentYellowCount` makes this an \$O(n^2)\$ solution when an \$O(n)\$ solution is possible — although to be fair, this doesn't really matter in practice when \$n\$ is so small) — but I do think the nested loops make the code harder to read.

We really only need two passes: in the first pass we identify the green letters, and in the second pass we iterate over the remaining letters and classify them as either yellow or gray. See the example implementation below.

---

Some JavaScript-specific nits:

- `let colors` can be `const colors`, and the `var`s used for `for` loop indices should be changed to `let`s to limit variable scope & avoid JavaScript's variable hoisting.
- all your equality checks can and should be using strict equality `===`.

---

Example implementation:

```js
const WORD_LENGTH = 5;

function computeColors(targetWord, guess) {
  const colors = Array(WORD_LENGTH).fill(null);
  const indicesOfIncorrectLettersInGuess = [];
  // Tracks the letters (and counts of those letters)
  // in `targetWord` that were not used up by `guess`
  const targetLetters = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < WORD_LENGTH; ++i) {
    let targetLetter = targetWord[i];

    if (targetLetter in targetLetters) {
      targetLetters[targetLetter]++;
    } else {
      targetLetters[targetLetter] = 1;
    }

    if (guess[i] === targetLetter) {
      colors[i] = "G";
      targetLetters[targetLetter]--;
    } else {
      indicesOfIncorrectLettersInGuess.push(i);
    }
  }

  for (const i of indicesOfIncorrectLettersInGuess) {
    let guessLetter = guess[i];

    if (guessLetter in targetLetters && targetLetters[guessLetter] > 0) {
      colors[i] = "Y";
      targetLetters[guessLetter]--;
    } else {
      colors[i] = "-";
    }
  }

  return colors.join("");
}

function test(targetWord, guess, expectedOutput) {
  const actualOutput = computeColors(targetWord, guess);
  console.assert(
    expectedOutput === actualOutput,
    {targetWord, guess, expectedOutput, actualOutput}
  );
}

test(
  "BURNT",
  "TOAST",
  "----G"
);

test(
  "MAXIM",
  "MAMMA",
  "GGY--"
);

test(
  "SWIFT",
  "IIWIS",
  "Y-Y-Y"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unrolling the loops gives a 40% performance improvement and, to my eyes, a big win in clarity. It locks you in to 5-letters-only, but one could code generate for the range of word sizes desired. This code assumes that the caller has validated the inputs.

```javascript
export function colorGuess(guessWord, targetWord) {
  //
  const [g0, g1, g2, g3, g4] = guessWord
  const [t0, t1, t2, t3, t4] = targetWord
  let   [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4] = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
  const unmatched = { a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0, e: 0, f: 0, g: 0, h: 0, i: 0, j: 0, k: 0, l: 0, m: 0, n: 0, o: 0, p: 0, q: 0, r: 0, s: 0, t: 0, u: 0, v: 0, w: 0, x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
  // 
  // for each letter in guess,
  // * mark it 'g' if it matches;
  // * otherwise, save it for later consideration
  //
  if (t0 === g0) { c0 = 'g' } else { unmatched[t0] += 1 }
  if (t1 === g1) { c1 = 'g' } else { unmatched[t1] += 1 }
  if (t2 === g2) { c2 = 'g' } else { unmatched[t2] += 1 }
  if (t3 === g3) { c3 = 'g' } else { unmatched[t3] += 1 }
  if (t4 === g4) { c4 = 'g' } else { unmatched[t4] += 1 }
  //
  // for each guess letter that is in the target but had no match,
  // set that slot's color to 'y' and remove it from further consideration.
  //
  if (unmatched[g0] && (c0 !== 'g')) { c0 = 'y'; unmatched[g0] -= 1 }
  if (unmatched[g1] && (c1 !== 'g')) { c1 = 'y'; unmatched[g1] -= 1 }
  if (unmatched[g2] && (c2 !== 'g')) { c2 = 'y'; unmatched[g2] -= 1 }
  if (unmatched[g3] && (c3 !== 'g')) { c3 = 'y'; unmatched[g3] -= 1 }
  if (unmatched[g4] && (c4 !== 'g')) { c4 = 'y'; unmatched[g4] -= 1 }
  //
  return c0 + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4
}
```

If you're interested in the performance, I did not-very-rigorous benchmarking of a few variations of that code. Unless noted, none of them changed the results by more than a couple percent, and since each makes tradeoffs in memory allocation / lookups / number of operations, I'd bet that certain VMs would prefer different choices.

- pre-seeding `unmatched = { a:0, b: 0, ...}` slightly outperformed initializing `unmatched = {}` and having to test `unmatched[t0] = (unmatched[t0] || 0) + 1` -- but when I moved it out of an else block (in the last snippet given), the second version was better.
- tracking the unmatched letters slightly outperformed using `indexOf()`, which is a secret inner loop but a machine-level one.
- no significant difference in `(unmatched[g0] && (c0 !== 'g'))` vs `((c0 !== 'g') && unmatched[g0])`. `unmatched[g0]` is false (saving the extra check) far more often than `c0 !== 'g'`, but `unmatched[g0]` always requires an index operation. I left it with the common-case-first reasoning
- using a Map was 3x slower than using an object for unmatched
- `const [t0, t1, t2, t3, t4] = targetWord` was noticeably faster than `[t0, t1, t2, t3, t4] = targetWord.split('')`.

version using indexOf:

```javascript
const NOPE = Symbol('NOPE')
export function colorGuess7(guessWord, targetWord) {
  // Validate.colorGuess({ guessWord, targetWord })
  const [g0, g1, g2, g3, g4]  = guessWord
  const target = targetWord.split('')
  let [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4] = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
  // 
  // for each letter in guess,
  // * mark it 'g' if it matches;
  // * otherwise, save it for later consideration
  //
  if (target[0] === g0) { target[0] = NOPE; c0 = 'g' }
  if (target[1] === g1) { target[1] = NOPE; c1 = 'g' }
  if (target[2] === g2) { target[2] = NOPE; c2 = 'g' }
  if (target[3] === g3) { target[3] = NOPE; c3 = 'g' }
  if (target[4] === g4) { target[4] = NOPE; c4 = 'g' }
  //
  // for each guess letter that had no match but is in the target,
  // set that slot's color to 'y' and remove it from further consideration.
  //
  if (c0 !== 'g') { const tgi = target.indexOf(g0); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c0 = 'y' } }
  if (c1 !== 'g') { const tgi = target.indexOf(g1); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c1 = 'y' } }
  if (c2 !== 'g') { const tgi = target.indexOf(g2); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c2 = 'y' } }
  if (c3 !== 'g') { const tgi = target.indexOf(g3); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c3 = 'y' } }
  if (c4 !== 'g') { const tgi = target.indexOf(g4); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c4 = 'y' } }
  return c0 + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4
}
```

similar performance:

```
export function colorGuess(guessWord, targetWord) {
  // Validate.colorGuess({ guessWord, targetWord })
  let [g0, g1, g2, g3, g4]  = guessWord
  const target = targetWord.split('')
  let [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4] = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
  //
  // for each letter in guess,
  // * mark it 'g' if it matches;
  // * otherwise, save it for later consideration
  //
  if (target[0] === g0) { target[0] = NOPE; c0 = 'g'; g0 = null }
  if (target[1] === g1) { target[1] = NOPE; c1 = 'g'; g1 = null }
  if (target[2] === g2) { target[2] = NOPE; c2 = 'g'; g2 = null }
  if (target[3] === g3) { target[3] = NOPE; c3 = 'g'; g3 = null }
  if (target[4] === g4) { target[4] = NOPE; c4 = 'g'; g4 = null }
  //
  // for each guess letter that had no match but is in the target,
  // set that slot's color to 'y' and remove it from further consideration.
  //
  let tgi
  tgi = target.indexOf(g0); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c0 = 'y' }
  tgi = target.indexOf(g1); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c1 = 'y' }
  tgi = target.indexOf(g2); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c2 = 'y' }
  tgi = target.indexOf(g3); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c3 = 'y' }
  tgi = target.indexOf(g4); if (tgi !== -1) { target[tgi] = NOPE; c4 = 'y' }
  return c0 + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4
}
```

You can change NOPE to the string `'NOPE'` if your javascript does not yet have Symbol.

Finally here is the fastest by a few percent version that I bothered to produce. In the second section, the `unmatched[g0] -= 1` calls will produce `NaN`s when that letter is absent; since `NaN` is falsy in javascript everything works correctly.

I prefer the first version I gave given that it is (a) not cheating, (b) within 5-10% of the fastest version, and (c) the most readable.

```
export function colorGuess(guessWord, targetWord) {
  //
  const [g0, g1, g2, g3, g4] = guessWord
  const [t0, t1, t2, t3, t4] = targetWord
  let   [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4] = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
  // this gave better performance than several obvious "optimizations" produced. 
  const unmatched = {}
  unmatched[t0] = 1
  unmatched[t1] = (unmatched[t1] || 0) + 1
  unmatched[t2] = (unmatched[t2] || 0) + 1
  unmatched[t3] = (unmatched[t3] || 0) + 1
  unmatched[t4] = (unmatched[t4] || 0) + 1
  //
  // for each letter in guess,
  // * mark it 'g' if it matches;
  // * otherwise, save it for later consideration
  //
  if (t0 === g0) { c0 = 'g'; unmatched[g0] -= 1 } // this will NaN on a miss, but that's OK: NaN is still falsy
  if (t1 === g1) { c1 = 'g'; unmatched[g1] -= 1 }
  if (t2 === g2) { c2 = 'g'; unmatched[g2] -= 1 }
  if (t3 === g3) { c3 = 'g'; unmatched[g3] -= 1 }
  if (t4 === g4) { c4 = 'g'; unmatched[g4] -= 1 }
  //
  // for each guess letter that had no match but is in the target,
  // set that slot's color to 'y' and remove it from further consideration.
  //
  if ((c0 !== 'g') && unmatched[g0]) { c0 = 'y'; unmatched[g0] -= 1 }
  if ((c1 !== 'g') && unmatched[g1]) { c1 = 'y'; unmatched[g1] -= 1 }
  if ((c2 !== 'g') && unmatched[g2]) { c2 = 'y'; unmatched[g2] -= 1 }
  if ((c3 !== 'g') && unmatched[g3]) { c3 = 'y'; unmatched[g3] -= 1 }
  if ((c4 !== 'g') && unmatched[g4]) { c4 = 'y'; unmatched[g4] -= 1 }
  //
  return c0 + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4
}
```